# Kernel#Array - How does Ruby interpret methods that have the same name as a constant?

Tags: ruby

When I'm coding in Ruby, to avoid type checks and `respond_to?`s and `nil` checks I often coerce objects into the type I expect. If I expect an `Array`, instead of `foo.nil? ? handle_nil(foo) : handle_array(foo)` I prefer to just `handle_foo(foo.to_a)` since `nil.to_a # => []`.

This doesn't work for everything, `1.to_a` raises `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_a' for 1:Integer`. `1.to_ary` raises the same error. `Array()` seems to solve the problem, handling what seems like any object and either making a sensible conversion to an `Array` or wrapping it in `[]`.

```
Array(nil)        # => []
Array('')         # => [""]
Array(Class)      # => [Class] 
Array(1)          # => [1]
Array(Object.new) # => [#<Object:0x007fdbd40df4c8>]
Array({})         # => []
Array(foo: :bar)  # => [[:foo, :bar]]
```

You can do the same thing with other classes too. `String()`, `Float()`... I'd used it a lot without thinking about the unusual syntax. I wanted to learn more about the implementation. Is it syntactic sugar for a special method, similar to `#[]`?

Both of these raise a `SyntaxError`

```
def self.(foo)
  puts foo
end

def self.()(foo)
  puts foo
end
```

You use `Array()` like you would use a method. Looking at the docs for `Kernel` it becomes clear that that's what's going on. The following works as you'd expect:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end

module Kernel
  def Thing(name)
    Thing.new(name)
  end
end

thing = Thing('name') # => #<Thing:0x007fefef89d8e8 @name="name">
thing.name # => "name"
```

You can also do this

```
HI = 'hi'.freeze

def HI(word)
  word
end

HI       # => "hi"
HI("ho") # => "ho"
```

My question is: How does Ruby interpret this? How does it distinguish between the method and the constant? Is this a silly question? Given "normal" behavior, one might expect Ruby to complain with a name warning when you define the method, or raise a `SyntaxError`. Does anyone know how Ruby handles this under the hood?

Thanks!

Comment: It is ruby parser who looks up the method when it sees parentheses, no matter casing (`_whatever()`) looks up constant when it sees a first capital and tries variable and then method with arity 0 when it sees a snake casing.

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes, this seems like an insightful and interesting question...

Comment: Quite long-winded question. IMO you can delete everything up to the last example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does Ruby interpret this? How does it distinguish between the method and the constant?

The rules are pretty much the same as with local variables: Ruby will assume it is a constant unless it's obvious that it isn't: constants can't have arguments, and constants can't have receivers.

```
FOO      # constant
self.FOO # message send
FOO()    # message send
FOO :bar # message send
```

> Given "normal" behavior, one might expect Ruby to complain with a name warning when you define the method, or raise a `SyntaxError`.

Why? Defining a method is perfectly legal syntactically (after all, that's what OO is all about), and `Array` is a perfectly legal Ruby identifier.